# "this pays almost double what the bookstore does." Is the verb "pay" or "double"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence-structure, adverbs, pronouns

> This pays almost double what the bookstore does.

I am a bit confused by the structure of this sentence.

Not quite sure about the meaning of this sentence.

For example, what is the verb? **pay** or **double**?

If **doulbe** is not a verb, is it a pronoun or adv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pays" is the verb.

"Double" is a noun that means "double the amount". In this case, it means *double the amount of money that the bookstore pays*.

Comment: "**double** the amount" here **double** is a verb. Right? In other words "This pays the amount of money which almost **doubles** what the bookstore does."

Comment: @StatsCruncher No, it's still a noun. The word "double" can be a noun that means an amount which is twice the size of the normal amount. <https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double>